# How to apply dashed border and border shadow to circle which is declared inside the radial gradient?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build a logo, there is one part of it where I need to create a gear like structure. The problem is the circle drawn in the logo is using radial-gradient like follows -

```
 background:radial-gradient(circle at 50% 66%, white 12%, transparent 12.5%);
```

How can I apply css properties like border and border-shadow to circle inside radial-gradient?
I cannot share the full code due to propriety issues. Another restriction is I am building logo using single div.

Comment: why building a circle using radial gradient when you can simply use border-radius and then apply the border? also if we cannot see what you want to build we cannot help you

Comment: If I use border radius then I need to use multiple divs. I am trying to build it in a single div.

Comment: you have 2 pseudo element that you can use with a div and again, we need to see what you want to build. No one can help or give a precise answer

Comment: Temani is right. You have `:before` and `:after`

Comment: Okay I will try that and let you know guys. Still is there any possible way to apply those properties on radial gradient circle?

Comment: no there is not, if you want an answer to that question BUT I am sure there is a ton of other ways to build what *only* you know

Comment: You're building a proprietary logo? Why not use SVG instead of such fickle and fragile method as CSS gradient and borders?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks for your suggestion, pseudo element solved my problem.